# Request Status Code 500 when running Python Script

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-requests, readlines

This is what i am suppose to do:

1. List all files in data/feedback folder
2. Scan all the files, and make a nested dictionary with Title, Name, Date & Feedback (All the files are in Title,Name, Date & Feedback format with each in a different line of file, that’s why using rstrip function)
3. Post the dictionary in The given url

Following is my code:

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import os
   import os.path
   import requests
   import json

   src = '/data/feedback/'
   entries = os.listdir(src)
   Title, Name, Date, Feedback = 'Title', 'Name', 'Date', 'Feedback'
   inputDict = {}
   for i in range(len(entries)):
       fileName = entries[i]
       completeName = os.path.join(src, fileName)
       with open(completeName, 'r') as f:
            line = f.readlines ()
            line tuple = (line[0],line[1],line[2],line[3])
            inputDict[fileName] = {}
            inputDict[fileName][Title] = line_tuple[0].rstrip()
            inputDict[fileName][Name] = line_tuple[1].rstrip()
            inputDict[fileName][Date] = line_tuple[2].rstrip()
            inputDict[fileName][Feedback] = line_tuple[3].rstrip()


   x = requests.get ("http://website.com/feedback")
   print (x.status_code)
   r = requests.post ("http://Website.com/feedback” , data=inputDict)
   print (r.status_code)
```

After i run it, get gives 200 code but post gives 500 code.
I just want to know if my script is causing the error or not ?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> r = requests.post ("http://Website.com/feedback” , data=inputDict)
> ```

If your rest api endpoint is expecting json data then the line above is not doing that; it is sending the dictionary `inputDict` as form-encoded, as though you were submitting a form on an HTML page.

You can either use the `json` parameter in the `post` function, which sets the content-type in the headers to `application/json`:

```
r = requests.post ("http://Website.com/feedback", json=inputDict)
```

or set the header manually:

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post("http://Website.com/feedback", data=json.dumps(inputDict), headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thank You for your help. 
Also, inputDict that i am making. Is my code that makes it, ok too ?

Comment: @NitishBerry Your code looks ok for the dictionary creation. Please try my answer for the `post`.

Comment: @NitishBerry status code 500 is an internal server error. If you're still getting after trying my answer I would check that your json data (from your dictionary) is in the correct format. There might be an error in there like incorrect key name, etc.

Comment: Sorry i slept and i haven’t had time to check it yet. Will update you soon after i do it. Thank So Much anyway

Comment: It helped. Thsnks